# How do I stop my Crispie/Crispy cake from going stale?

Tags: baking, storage-method, cake, storage-lifetime, marshmallow

I make a Crispie type cake, but with my own homemade ingredients, Mallows,etc when I make it with shop bought Marshmallows etc it lasts for weeks, when I make it with my own ingredients it goes soft/dry, the crispies loose their crisp and the gooeyness goes. How do I solve this? Would thicker packaging work? or vacuum sealer. At the moment they are just on trial and are being ept in thin "boil in a bag" vacuum packaging for home use. 
Can anyone give me any advice that might help me please. 
Thank you Sarah

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know of Crispie type cakes. Can you post a recipe?

Comment: Marshmallows, butter and puffed rice

Comment: So what is also known as a [rice krispy treat](https://www.ricekrispies.com/en_US/recipes/the-original-treats-recipe.html)?

Comment: Yes, however, I am English, so over here we use a C instead of a K. :)

Comment: How do you make the crisped rice?

Comment: Sounds like you've got water migrating from your home-made marshmallow to your puffed rice. Packaging won't (can't) solve that.

Comment: How would I stop that? Because even shop bought marshmallows contain water. Do you have any suggestions that might help me solve the problem? Many thanks

Comment: I also buy the crisped rice as it is.

Answer (score 1):

I usually store them in an airtight container, with wax paper underneath each layer. They keep very dry stored like this. It could be that your bag is not sealing 100%